# Using TSimpleDataset for multiple purposes

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Delphi 2010

I am trying to use TSimpleDataset for multiple purposes.

```
var
 q: tsimpledataset;
 row: String;
 n: Integer;
begin
 q:=tsimpledataset.create(nil);
 q.connection:= SQLConnection1 ; 
 q.dataset.commandtype:=ctQuery ;
 q.dataset.commandtext:='select lastid from last_id where tablename=:ARow';
 q.Params.Assign(q.Dataset.Params);
 ShowMessage(q.dataset.commandtext);
 row:='accounts';
 q.params[0].asstring:=  row;
  q.open;
 if q.isempty then
  raise exception.create('No matching row found in LAST_ID table.');
 n:=q.fieldbyname('lastid').asinteger +1;
 q.close;
 q.dataset.commandtype:=ctQuery ;
 q.dataset.commandtext:='update last_id set lastid=22';
 q.execute;  //exception Here!
end;
```

I get the following error on the q.Execute line:

Missing Data provider or Data packet

Seems to be a problem with the closing of the TSimpleDataset and the reuse of it.
It would work if i freed it and recreated it and reassined the properties and new properties to use it for an execute.  However, i would like to not have to do that. I would like to be able to close it, and then assign a new CommandText and reuse it.

I have researched and read alot of comments on the internet reagrding not using the buggy TSimpleDataset, to use the three other components instead (ClientDataSet, DataSetProvider and SQLDataSet).  You would think that by 2010 Embarcadero would have worked out any issues with the TSimpleDataset.

Is there any workaround other than having to swictch to something other than a TSimpleDataset?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have much experience with TSimpleDataSet in particular, but in general I wouldn't reuse datasets at all. Just put them on a datamodule, configure them using the IDE as much as you can, and don't write all that code to reuse a single component while you can have two. They don't consume much memory (hardly any at all), so don't be bothered by that either.

Comment: Sorry, but thats not an option. I need to create and use them at runtime, and use them for multiple purposes.

Comment: TSimpleDataSet isn't a serious component you'll quickly outgrow it. It's my guess that's why Embarcadero might be neglecting it. If you want to simplify the process of dropping the 3 component TClientDataSet, TDataSetProvider, TSQLDataSet look into [component templates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_Component_Templates)

Comment: If you're using a "last_id" table to generate unique identifiers you're looking for troubles. That approach doesn't work if you have more than one user accessing the database, unless you serialize wholly the access to the table (or at least each row). If access is concurrent, you can obtain duplicates easily. If your database supports sequences, generators or autogenerated fields is far better to use them, they ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Really, cause our app is used in two major corporations with each with multiple hundreds of users. LastId approach works fine!

Comment: Not sure why everyone keeps giving me a negative for this question. I merely asked if "Is there any workaround other than having to swictch to something other than a TSimpleDataset?" - instead i get answers repeating stuff that i said i wasn't interested in , such as "3 component TClientDataSet, TDataSetProvider, TSQLDataSet"

Comment: Don't know what database you're using, but unless it locks the whole table and serialize itself (slowing down everything), or it allow for dirty reads (reading uncomitted transactions) you're just lucky. That approach is flawed, and can be easily demonstrated. Think about two concurrent transaction, both reading and incrementing the same last_id before commiting and let other transctions see the new value.

Comment: Let me see, Oracle, MS Sql Server, and Interbase are three we currently support. Oracle and MS Sql Server being used at two very large Blue Cross Blue Shield's.  They have both been up and running more than two years, processing over a million claims a week through our application. LAST_ID working just fine. You are getting off from the subject of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the second commandtype be.

```
q.DataSet.CommandType := ctUpdate;
```

Comment: -1. Only possible values for `CommandType` are `ctQuery`, `ctTable`, `ctStoredProc` and `ctServerMethod`.

Comment: Ok noticed that `ctUpdate` was not included in the subset used by `TInternalSQLDataset`.
I noticed that you don't clear the parameters, would it help to do a `q.Params.Clear`?

Comment: I have tried the Paams.clear, and it changes nothing. Get the same error.